# Amazon Web Services (AWS) - retrieving reviews - is this still possible?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

new to AWS & this Services. I'm interested in looking up reviews by (ASIN,) tuple. I can see that the Product Advertising API returns a URL to a page (for embedding in an IFRAME) containing the URLs. etx.  Well I am interested in a machine-readable format of the review data, if possible.

on a sidenote: I heard that the Product Advertising API will no longer return customer 
reviews content and instead will return a link to customer reviews content hosted
on Amazon.com. You will be able to display customer reviews on your site using that link

btw: i saw two references:

> This plug-in embeds an Amazon Web Services request into a content
>   article. The amazon web services content plugin works for Joomla 1.5x
>   to 3.0x. It requires an API key, which you can easily obtain by
>   opening an account at http://aws.amazon.com/  You will also require a
>   valid Amazon Associates ID, which you obtain through creating an
>   account here. You will require permission for each domain on which you
>   wish to use your ID, you can obtain this through your Amazon
>   Associates account. This is important, the Amazon product advertising
>   API will not return result without this.

see Examples, that use several methodologies: http://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Table/examples/Amazon-Plugin-Examples/

Amazon Plugin Example 3: listing item ids http://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Amazon-Plugin-Examples/amazon-plugin-example-3-listing-item-ids.html

**BTW** :SOME TEXTS MAY SHED A LIGHT: Do any of the AWS APIs/Services provide access to the product reviews for items sold by Amazon? I'm interested in looking up reviews by (ASIN, user_id) tuple. I can see that the Product Advertising API returns a URL to a page (for embedding in an IFRAME) containing the URLs, but I am interested in a machine-readable format of the review data, if possible.

CF: [Is there an Amazon.com API to retrieve product reviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811259/is-there-an-amazon-com-api-to-retrieve-product-reviews)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at a sample of my XML I had printed a while back and the only data returned for customer reviews is that `<IFrameURL>`.

I am pretty sure I looked for the same thing you are looking for and came up empty handed. AWS does not make that data available in their XML datafeed. Any attempt to display that data by some other means is likely to be a violation of their API License Agreement.

Comment: This question is closely related and has an answer with a nice quote from Amazon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811259