# Retrieve product information and product reviews from amazon

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am new to `amazon aws`. I want to extract Product details and product reviews. I've googled this question and I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811259/is-there-an-amazon-com-api-to-retrieve-product-reviews) link. But this is not getting me anywhere. So please help me.

**P.S.** : I want to implement this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to try, [Amazon Java Query](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2478) to a java sample to send a signed request to lookup at amazon. I hope this gets you a little closer to what you are looking for. This is similar to something I am looking to do for walmart but they seem very tight with providing 3rd party access to their data.