# BeautifulSoup 'find()' returns NoneType Value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, nonetype

I've just started to try and code a price tracker with Python, and have already ran into an error I don't understand. This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Corsair-Platinum-Mechanical-Keyboard-Backlit/dp/B082GR814B/'
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0."
                         "4103.116 Safari/537.36"}
targetPrice = 150


def getPrice():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()    # Error happens here
    print(price)


if True:
    getPrice()
```

I see this part soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice") returns a value of 'None' thus the AttributeError. I don't understand why it returns a 'None' value. Only ONCE did the code actually work and printed the product price, and never again. I ran the script again after the single successful attempt without changing anything, and got the AttributeError consistantly again.

I've also tried the following:

Used html5lib and lxml instead of html.parser.
Different id's, to see if I can access different parts of a site.
Other User Agents.
I also downloaded a similar program from github that uses the exact same code to see if it would run, but it didn't either.

What is happening here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting captcha page. Try to set more HTTP headers as in browser to get correct page. When I set `Accept-Language` http header I cannot reproduce the error anymore:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Corsair-Platinum-Mechanical-Keyboard-Backlit/dp/B082GR814B/'
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
}

def getPrice():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    print(price)


getPrice()
```

Prints:

```
$195.99
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it. So, scraping isn't "actually allowed" on Amazon?

Comment: @WilmerKluever Better read their Terms of Service. I suppose they have some official API to get results like this.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know too much about HTML. How would I extract the text from here? <span class="currency plus currency-module_currency_29IIm">R 1,739</span>             I live in South Africa so I use other online shops. Hence the Rand currency

Comment: @WilmerKluever I would use `soup.select_one('span.currency').text`, but I recommend to open a new question. Every site/eshop is a little bit specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `soup` after `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')`.

Amazon knows that you are trying to crawl them and hence the page you think they are returning, they are not.

[Getting blocked when scraping Amazon (even with headers, proxies, delay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366099/getting-blocked-when-scraping-amazon-even-with-headers-proxies-delay)