# What is the best way to extract text from Amazon listings into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**PURPOSE:**
I am trying to extract product features(bullet points) from Amazon.com listings into a Google Spreadsheet.

**PROBLEM:**
I have tried 4 different methods but none has worked.

- IMPORTXML:
  `IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JD2GDKN","//ul/li/showHiddenFeatureBullets")`
- IMPORTHTML:
  `IMPORTHTML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JD2GDKN","list",1)`
- REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML):
  `REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JD2GDKN","//feature-bullets"),"Amazon.com: ","")`
- custom functions: `productFeatures ("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JD2GDKN")`

---

```
function productFeatures(url) {   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.match(/<span class="a-list-item">/);
  return match && match [1] ? match[1] : 'Title not found'; 
}
// via https://screencast.com/t/pkxiFcg6my
```

---

:

This are the responses I get:

> custom function:(https://screencast.com/t/WL9Ay6UQemK)
>
> Response from running "IMPORTHTML": "Import content is empty"
>
> Response for running "IMPORTXML": "Imported Xml content can not be parsed."

**GOAL:**
I'd appreciate any help resolving this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811259/is-there-an-amazon-com-api-to-retrieve-product-reviews

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with regex but after some research I was able to get this to work:

I used the custom function below to get the first bullet point

```
function BP1(url) {   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.match(/<li><span.*>([^<]*)<\/span><\/li>/g);
  return match  && match ? match[7]: 'BP not found';
}
```

For each subsequent product features I just created a corresponding function that raises the match number by 1. For example, feature five has the following function:

```
function BP5(url) {   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.match(/<li><span.*>([^<]*)<\/span><\/li>/g);
  return match  && match ? match[12]: 'BP not found';
}
```

The only problem with this is that it pulls xml text at the front and back. I'm guessing someone with more understanding of all this could fix that. I just use the LEFT(), RIGHT(), and LEN() functions to clean up the results

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(bp1(url), LEN(bp1(url))-39),LEN(bp1(url))-66)
```

Hope this helps, I know it's not a perfect solution but it gets the job done for me.